# Profiling CPU Instructions on iPhone

Tags: ios, profiling

I would like to be able to profile a particular C function within an iOS application to see which CPU instructions it uses, and how often they are used. What is a simple way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to check out the Time Profiler tool in Instruments. Check out the [User Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004652-CH1-SW1) for some detailed information on how to best make use of it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have looked into the Time Profiler a bit, but I am not sure if it gives me everything I am looking for. Ideally, I would like to see all of the CPU instructions in my code, nicely separated by which function they belong to. I would then like to see how many times a particular function is called, so I can get an idea of how often each instruction is used. Is there any way this could be done using Instruments?

Comment: Aha, I guess I misunderstood your question a bit. I'm not quite sure if instruments goes that deep, but from my limited experience with the Time Profiler it seems to give a higher level view than you're looking for.

Comment: I may have been too brief in the original description. I found out that there is a way to view the assembly code for a particular file in Xcode (related files -> assembly). Maybe I can manually combine that with Instruments Time Profiler data to get something useful...